# "bitmap size exceeds 32bits" at buildDrawingCache on KitKat devices

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am working on a rather simple application. The app has the following piece of code under the hood:

```
...
mRootContentView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));
int[] screenDimensions = AndroidUtils.getScreenDimesions(getContext());
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenDimensions[0], screenDimensions[1], Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
mRootContentView.layout(0, 0, screenDimensions[0], screenDimensions[1]);
mRootContentView.draw(c);
...
```

As you no doubt have already guessed, it gets a "screenshot" of the whole current activity.

After the android v 4.4.2 (KitKat) realease I've faced with a strange exception in my ACRA reports, telling me this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:809)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:769)
at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:13608)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14154)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
at net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer.dispatchDraw(MenuDrawer.java:665)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
. . .
```

This exception is only thrown on a KitKat devices, such as nexus 7 and nexus 5.

***EDIT***

I've also tried this:

```
mRootContentView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mRootContentView.buildDrawingCache();
bitmap = mRootContentView.getDrawingCache();
```

Nothing's changed.

Comment: sou should measure before layout

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your exception is being thrown from [GraphicsJNI::allocateJavaPixelRef](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android/graphics/Graphics.cpp). The exception is thrown, as you might have guessed, when the Bitmap's size exceeds 32 bits in total.

Since you are only obtaining a "screenshot" which probably does not require alpha channel, have you thought about trying `Bitmap.Config.RGB565` rather than `RGBA8888`? I'm not certain if it will prevent all crashes, however.